# Tomcat not starting

Tags: eclipse, spring, tomcat, ant, struts

i always get the following error when trying to start Tomcat in eclipse (or also from the terminal with this specific war file)the build using ant is successful of course:

```
08.08.2011 08:21:02 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SCHWERWIEGEND: Servlet  threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: dea.alo.aloWeb.spring.StxxDelegatingRequestProcessor
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1678)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1523)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
at com.oroad.stxx.plugin.StxxPlugin.initRequestProcessorClass(StxxPlugin.java:153)
at com.oroad.stxx.plugin.StxxPlugin.init(StxxPlugin.java:102)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.initModulePlugIns(ActionServlet.java:1158)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.init(ActionServlet.java:473)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1216)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1135)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1031)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4957)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$3.call(StandardContext.java:5284)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$3.call(StandardContext.java:5279)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

It runs perfectly on a pc using linux and eclipse galileo, but not on my mac using eclipse indigo. the libraries are all in place..does anyone have an idea what the problem might be?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like I syncyronisation problem I often have.

- Refresh the Workspace
- Project Build (most time not needed) - But make sure that there are no build errors
- Then run the two tasks from the Servers/(tomcat) Context menu

  - Clean...
  - Clean Tomcat Working Directory

If this all does not help, then Remove the application from the Server, clean the Server and Deploy the application again to the server.

Comment: thanks for the tips!unfortunately the problem still exists..i'm kinda running out of ideas...i added all the libraries again to the build path, tried different jre versions, checked the dependencies...i would really appreciate some fresh input:)

Comment: Problem solved - don't ask me how, i played a little with the libraries in the build path and somehow it works now:) thx for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The class StxxDelegatingRequestProcessor is missing in your classpath -> "ClassNotFoundException: dea.alo.aloWeb.spring.StxxDelegatingRequestProcessor"
I think you copied the struts conf from a site but not the class :)